# Access the n-th child of root element in XSLT

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt

I'm parsing this XSLT file

```
merge_file = merge_xslt(initial_message, depth=et.XSLT.strparam("5"))
```

where initial_message = et.parse(initial.xslt')

What i want to achieve is to pass to the initial.xslt the depth param. The initial.xslt code is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="xsl:template[not(@name)]">
     <xsl:param name="depth" />
     <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*"/>
        <!-- The path /*/*[depth]/* is used to select the third child element of the root
        element of the document, and then all of its child elements. -->
        <xsl:copy-of select="document('second.xslt')/*/*[$depth]/*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But this approach is not working and im wondering what im missing. The depth variable is not passing

Comment: What does `merge_xslt` do exactly? It is not sure whether you process XSLT with XSLT.

Comment: merge_xslt = et.XSLT(xsl_merge) and xsl_merge = et.parse('xslt_merge.xslt')

Comment: So you are now trying to run that XSLT with lxml? It is not clear what your input is, which code you want to execute and which result you want. Is all XSLT? Are you aware of using a namespace alias? Doesn't libxslt give an error when encounter `version="2.0"` code?

Comment: Also, it might help to ensure the parameter is a number, not a string. Or to use `[number($depth)]` or `[position() = $depth]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run XSLT 1.0 with Python lxml I would suggest to use `version="1.0"` for better error reporting.

As for the code, if you want to be able to set the global parameter `depth` from outside then it needs to be declared outside of any `xsl:template`, as a child of `xsl:stylesheet` e.g.

```
<xsl:param name="depth" />

<xsl:template match="xsl:template[not(@name)]">
     <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*"/>
        <!-- The path /*/*[depth]/* is used to select the third child element of the root
        element of the document, and then all of its child elements. -->
        <xsl:copy-of select="document('second.xslt')/*/*[$depth]/*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Make sure you pass in a number value or better use `[position() = $depth]` or `[number($depth)]` if you can't assure from Python you pass in a number.